# Docker macvlan need to publish ports?

Tags: networking, debian, docker, port, bridge

I'm doing a macvlan bridge... now the question comes spontaneously ...
Being that with macvlan, the container is exposed directly to the network, does it need to expose the ports with the -p option at startup?

Thanks in advance for the reply ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer... After I connected a container that was started with the "-p" option (to expose the ports on the network), to an 802.1q macvlan bridge, they automatically disappeared from the "docker ps" list all published ports.

So I would say it shouldn't be necessary to publish the ports of a container on that type of network.

Regards, MrTaik.